# 500 Error after changing wordpress prefix

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I changed the Wordpress database prefix with iThemes Security from the default wp_, but now it gives always 500 Error at loading the site :-(
I checked the database, and wp-config, and they seem to match, the plug-in changed the prefix correctly, also, I deleted the .htaccess file and removed the plugin from the wp-content folder.
Any idea how could I get the site back?

Comment: Check error log on your Apache for some useful information.

Comment: It says: [Thu Nov 19 04:15:03 2015] [error] [client 5.38.129.36] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp() in /.../wp-blog-header.php on line 14 any idea what is it?

Comment: can you log in to the dashboard?

Comment: No the dashboard is also with 500 Error

Comment: Did you take a database backup before you changed the prefix? What happens if you move back to that one?

Comment: I carefully checked now my wp-config.php file and it was truncated, missing the end of the file (from languages defining), so I restored it from the sample, and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I carefully checked now my wp-config.php file and it was truncated, missing the end of the file (from languages defining), so I restored it from the sample, and it works now!
It was some mistake while the file was updated on the server (momentary interruption?).
Thanks.